# Prove that $|A_1\cup A_2\cup\ldots\cup A_{11}|\geq 165$

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> Let $A$ be a set with $|A|=225$, meaning that $A$ has 225 elements. Suppose further that there are eleven subsets $A_1, \ldots, A_{11}$ of $A$ such that $|A_i|=45$ for $1\leq i\leq11$ and $|A_i\cap A_j|=9$ for $1\leq i<j\leq11$. Prove that $|A_1\cup A_2\cup\ldots\cup A_{11}|\geq 165$, and give an example for which equality holds.

Let $x = |A_1\cup A_2\cup\ldots\cup A_{11}|,$ and let $a_i$ be the number of times the element $i$ appears in over all $11$ subsets, for $1 \leq i \leq k.$

Now, for equality to happen, then $a_i=3$ for all $i.$

An example would be nice too.

Comment: See https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c5h404364p2254871

Comment: @player3236 i want hint and not solution , thanks!

Comment: Hint: Set up the standard incidence matrix and count the number of column (or row) pairs. Bound this in 2 different ways, knowing that there are $11\times 45 = 495$ ones that occur in $k$ columns, to conclude that $k \geq 165$.